# Backup Internet Providers?

Tags: networking, backup, internet

One of my clients who has multiple sites has some reliablity issues with their AT&T T1s.  At one locations they're using [Business Only Broadband](http://www.bobbroadband.com), a backup microwave internet link.  However, it's not avaliable at their other site.  What are some other viable solutions?  Right now I've got them setup with a [cradlepoint CBA250](http://3gstore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=200&products_id=1072) with a verizon card that has a 5GB limit as a backup until I find a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather hard to answer this question, with out knowing your price range, bandwidth/latency needs, and geographic location.

Somethings to research are,

- Satellite back haul
- 3G/4G (Which it appears you already are)
- WiMax (Clear etc)
- Local Wireless ISPs (more uncommon by sometimes available)  (Clearwire is an example)
- FiOS or other Fiber Provider
- Cable Lines
- DSL Line
- Dialup

Some of the above offer very cheap rates for business users because they don't guarantee bandwidth.

Another consideration, if you have systems that need to stay connected, it may make sense to place these systems in co-location that is multi-honed etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be wireless?  If not, get another T1, Cable, or DSL from a different ISP.

Answer (score 0):

T1s are more expensive due to being 'dedicated' and most often advertised as more 'reliable' than DSL or Wireless.  I would suggest demanding AT&T to fix the 'unreliability issue' with the threat of moving your business somewhere else if they do not follow-up with your request.  I deal a lot with service companies, sometimes you have to be extra annoying to get things rolling... don't hesitate to ask for the manager, or the manager's boss.